# Library to differentiate people by their voice timbre

Tags: audio, voice

Say there are 3 people in the room. Each of them have a unique voice timbre. I want to recognize people by their timbre and know who's speaking.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The task of taking a long contiguous audio recording and splitting it up in chunks in which only one speaker is speaking - without any prior knowledge about the voice characteristics of each speaker - is called "Speaker diarization". You can find links to research code on the [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speaker_diarisation).

If you have prior recordings of each voice, and would rather do classification, this is a slightly different problem (Speaker recognition or Speaker identification). Software tools for that are available [here](http://mistral.univ-avignon.fr/) (note that general purposes speech recognition packages like Sphinx or HTK are flexible enough to be coaxed into doing that).

Comment: Wow! Thanks for such an extensive answer. I'm interested in doing this live, basically detecting when and who is speaking and maybe writing that to a separate file, or just writing to log when and who spoke.

Comment: Did you find any library which works in real time. I came across IBM Watson Speech Recognition API, but it is not open source.